# Add transparency to color to simulate disabled state

Tags: android, android-styles

I have the following selector for my buttons in `style/v21`

// button_color_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Disable background -->
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#dfdfdf"/>

<!-- Enabled background -->
<item android:color="@color/buttonColor"/>
</selector>
```

now instead of explicitly saying when the button is disabled make it grey. Can I not some how say, Just make it a faded / transparent verion of `@color/buttonColor`

Also does anyone know what the standard android transparancy for a disabled button is?

I still do not know why in `v21` we now have to explicitly give the disabled color. pre v21 it worked just fine.

Comment: is there any way I can apply an alpha value on `@color/buttonColor` instead of having a disabled and enabled button color defined?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the alpha and disable it on code, like this:

```
button.setAlpha(.5f);
button.setClickable(false);
```

This could be inside a check on the creation of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is to simply add the alpha value to the color value itself in your colors.xml.

For example, if your button color is red: `#ff0000`, just add a 50% alpha value to the front of it: `#80ff0000`
(80 hex corresponds to 128 decimal = 50% of 256 (ff hex)

Now you have a color that is just a slightly "faded" version of your original color. The alpha value is just a percentage, 00-99, so you can play with the numbers to get the right amount of fade on your color.

Comment: is there any way I can apply an alpha value on `@color/buttonColor` instead of having a disabled and enabled button color?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, not without adjusting the alpha in code or in the alpha attribute as suggested in some of the other answers. I do it this way in my projects, and I just have something like `buttonColor` and `buttonColor_disabled` or something similar. It's one line of code and does not add any complexity to your app logic.

Comment: `#50ff0000` doesn't correspond to a 50% alpha, the value is interpreted in hexadecimal just like the color channels. To have a 50% alpha you should write `#80ff0000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alpha for change the transparency of the object

android:alpha="0.0" thats invisible

android:alpha="0.5" see-through

android:alpha="1.0" full visible